# Convert varchar to int in conjunction with substring in sql

Tags: sql, casting, int, substring

I am trying to sort my results in order of street number, and because the street number is varchar it doesn't place them in numerical order when I use the following query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(given," ", middle," ", surname) AS People_who_live_in_Queen_Street, SUBSTRING(street, 1, 2) AS Street_Number
FROM people
WHERE street LIKE '%queen%'
ORDER BY Street_Number
```

I have tried using CAST

```
SELECT CONCAT(given," ", middle," ", surname) AS People_who_live_in_Queen_Street, CAST(SUBSTRING(street, 1, 2) AS INT) AS Street_Number
FROM people
WHERE street LIKE '%queen%'
ORDER BY Street_Number
```

and it doesn't work. Had the same problem when I tried CONVERT. Not sure where I am going wrong. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert to a number.  Perhaps something like this:

```
ORDER BY CAST(Street_Number as DECIMAL(10, 2))
```